# Jquery FitText plugin for images?

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, resize

is there a plugin similar to jquery's FitText plugin that can be used on Images?  What I'm trying to accomplish is to have images automatically resized to fit whatever display i'm in.

Answer (score 2):

Try Jquery ImageFit plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-imagefit-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

fitText is useful because it you can't really resize the `font-size` in CSS. But for images, I think the `max-width` property is enough.